# Hibernate inserts child into parent table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the followings at Java level:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORD_DOC")
public class WordDoc extends Doc {}

@Entity
public class Doc extends BaseDoc {}

@Entity
public abstract class BaseDoc {}
```

And the following tables in the DB:

```
WORD_DOC
id         int8
version    int8
...

BASEDOC
id         int8
...
```

When I try to save a WordDoc, the Hibernate fails with the following error:

```
STATEMENT: insert into BaseDoc (..., ..., .....) values (..., ..., .....)
ERROR: column "version" of relation "basedoc" does not exist at character 40
```

Why it tries to persist the WordDoc into the parent class's table? It has several additional attributes so it not fit into that.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate supports four inheritance mapping strategies. If you don't specify any (like in your example), [the `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy is used](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-single-table). This means all your entities end up in the `BaseDoc` table (which is what you observed).

See this article to see how to use a different mapping strategy: [Inheritance Strategies with JPA and Hibernate – The Complete Guide](https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/).

In your case, you might need `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`. The first maps every concrete (non-abstract) class to its own table that includes all the information of its superclass(es). The second maps *all* classes, including the abstract ones, to their own tables, but requires joins.

Comment: Thanks! In the description it shows that "A mapped superclass is not an entity, and there is no table for it." But in my case the superclass has a table.

Comment: Like I said, there are four strategies to choose from. In that case, you seem to need the `JOINED` strategy.